# Understanding the double exclamation point

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what exactly the double exclamation mark does. Yes, I saw [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) with lots of answers. So I know in principle what it does, but I don't know why one would ever need to use it.

From what I understand, it converts the value to a boolean. So let's say I have the following code:

```
var myBool = !!(index === 0 || index > len);
```

Can't I just leave out the `!!` and I will get the same result:

```
var myBool = (index === 0 || index > len);
```

What do I gain by adding `!!`? Is't it already a boolean vaule?

Comment: Okay, what you didn't understand in the other question? If it's already a boolean value, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You will get the same result. In this case, it's redundant.

Comment: @Barmar, I just closed it and reopened. Did you read what OP has written?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't read carefully either

Comment: @PraveenKumar So it would only make sense to use it if I do this: `var myBool = !!index`?

Comment: You would use it when you want to force the coercion.  Eg `var myBool = !!something;` or `var myBool = !!(something || something_else);`.  You wouldn't use it on an expression that is already guaranteed to be a boolean, you would use it on an expression that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @Horay yes, in general, if you're not _sure_ what the value is, you can use double negation to convert it. By the way, the alternative is to use `Boolean(value)` instead of `!!value` which will do the same conversion.

Comment: @Horay True... `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of `!!` is to canonicalize any type of truthy or falsey value to the corresponding boolean value.

If the value is already known to be a boolean, such as the result of a comparison operator, there's no point in it and it's redundant. So it's useless in the example you gave.